# Importing keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to import keras and the code returns an error about tensorflow.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

and the error says:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gonza/Documents/Projects/jeremiah/neuralNet.py", line 6, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Users\gonza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\gonza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\gonza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\gonza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\gonza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like tensorflow is not found. You need to install tensorflow in order to use keras library.

If you already installed tensorflow, try to uninstall and install it again.

```
    sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow 
    pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

You can verify the install by running this command:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is related to TensorFlow. TensorFlow may not be installed or installed incorrectly. please check TensorFlow installation